# Regex for specific strings/paths

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression to match many specific paths/strings but I can't figure it out.

E.g.

../foo/hoo/something.js -> Needs to match **../foo/hoo/**

../foo/bar/somethingElse.js -> Needs to match **../foo/bar/**

../foo/something-else.js -> Needs to match **../foo/**

What I tried with no luck is the following regex:

```
/\..\/foo\/|bar\/|hoo\//g
```

Comment: What's the key? In first two you want to match both dirs, in the third one dir and filename...

Comment: Thanks for your comment I miss-typed my case. The case is as shown in updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work out for you:

```
/(\.\.\/foo\/(hoo\/|bar\/)?)/
```

https://regex101.com/r/1aTf7y/1

So you select `../foo/` at first and then have a group that can either contain `hoo/` or `bar/`. And the question mark allows 0 or one instances.

If you want to be a little less specific, you could also do

```
/(\.\.\/[^\/]+\/(hoo\/|bar\/)?)/
```

The `[^\/]+` allows all characters except for a slash

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex

```
(\/[^\/\s]+)+(?=\/)
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/QkPyL3/1)

```js
function match(str){
  console.log(str.match(/(\/[^\/\s]+)+(?=\/)/)[0]);
}

match('./foo/hoo/something.js');
match('../foo/bar/somethingElse.js');
match('../foo/something-else.js');
```

Comment: This also matches strings which do not start from '../foo'

Answer (score 0):

This should be the regex for matching all dirs without filename.

```
 /^(.*[/])[^/]+$/
```